# Android: Stopping the LogCat window from showing

Tags: android, eclipse

I just upgraded to the latest version of the SDK (version 19) and now notice that the LogCat window always shows up when I am debugging. I closed it but it then comes back again a short while later. I find this annoying. How can I permanently keep it closed.

Comment: Do you mean that your IDE keeps showing the logcat window?

Comment: Yes, if I close it, it comes back a while later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Preferences > Android > LogCat and uncheck "Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace".

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

Make your own perspective.
Right-click on the perspective when it is in the state you want to save.
Choose "Save As".